# Order of map getting changed automatically in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having a map object with a group elements with key and value pairs. The key is string dates with values as messages. I am storing the map object in one `$scope` variable when I print it with `console.log` I am getting the data in past dates to current date as key in ascending order.

Refer the below code snippet for the map object. But when I see in html the order is getting changed automatically. Can anybody say why the order getting changed?

**JSON data of MAP**

```
{"Mar 13, 2017":[{"msg":"Hello Mar 13","created":1489404180586},
"Mar 22, 2017":[{"msg":"Hello Mar 22","created":1490185383843}],
"Apr 16, 2017":[{"msg":"Hello Apr 16","created":1492329078569}],
"Apr 24, 2017":[{"msg":"Hello Apr 24","created":1493055290741},
"Apr 25, 2017":[{"msg":"Hello Apr 25","created":1493081729979}]}
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat='(key, value) in map'>    
 <p><span>Apr 16,2017</span></p>
 <div ng-repeat="msg in value | orderBy : 'created'">
 <div>
   <div>           
      <span>Hello Apr 16</span>
   </div>
   <p><span>Apr 24,2017</span></p>
 <div ng-repeat="msg in value | orderBy : 'created'">
 <div>
   <div>           
      <span>Hello Apr 24</span>
   </div>
   <p><span>Apr 25,2017</span></p>
 <div ng-repeat="msg in value | orderBy : 'created'">
 <div>
   <div>           
      <span>Hello Apr 25</span>
   </div>
   <p><span>Mar 13,2017</span></p>
 <div ng-repeat="msg in value | orderBy : 'created'">
 <div>
   <div>           
      <span>Hello Mar13</span>
   </div>
   <p><span>Mar 22,2017</span></p>
 <div ng-repeat="msg in value | orderBy : 'created'">
 <div>
   <div>           
      <span>Hello Mar22</span>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us, your html code, what you tried.

Comment: added  the html code above

Comment: What you want to achieve? Your code is confusing http://plnkr.co/edit/yVDpDn6wZZRVVPRlUU4a?p=preview

Comment: Your map isn't changing automatically, your are just ordering your data in the html view with an `angular filter`, so what you see when you print the map in the controller is the original data. The best approach in your case is order your data in the controller before repeating it. Even, you can inject `$filter` in your controller if you want.

Comment: @AayushiJain I want the data in date wise ascending order but I am not able to achieve it.

Comment: @Karthik it's in ascending order already: http://plnkr.co/edit/ovZ0wiu3mn7KtM0ztQnM?p=preview